# Improve performance of the SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, and I have the this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMessagesByDates]
      (@orderdateFirst varchar(50), 
       @orderdateLast varchar(50))      
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT TOP 100 [RecordID]
      ,[MessageID]
      ,[ProcessName]
      ,[ProcessInstanceID]
      ,[Arrival]
      ,[MessageDateTime]
      ,[RecvFileName]
      ,[ArchivePath]
      ,[SubjectID]
      ,[SrcMessageID]
      ,[SourceSystem]
      ,[SourceLocation]
      ,[MsgKey1]
      ,[MsgKey2]
      ,[MsgKey3]
  FROM [Messages].[dbo].[MessagesLog]
  WHERE 
      [Arrival] BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @orderdateFirst) 
                    AND CONVERT(datetime, @orderdateLast)
  ORDER BY
      [Arrival] DESC
END
```

[Arrival] (datetime type) is a clustered unique index in [MessagesLog] Table.
[RecordID] (bigint type) is the second index key column in my clustered index.

How can I improve the performance of the procedure above ?
I'm working on thousands of rows and it takes a lot of time.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! So in your case: change the parameter types to `DATE` and stop using `CONVERT` on your date columns - that'll speed things up significantly

Comment: Please post the execution plan. If `Arrival` is the clustered index I would expect to see an index seek that returns the 100 rows efficiently. Also please clarify what " a lot of time" is. Maybe the query is encountering blocking from concurrent uncommitted transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One performance improvement would be to `CONVERT` your `varchar` to `datetime` prior to the `SELECT` statement.

At the moment you are making 2 converts per record. If you have thousands of rows that will cause a performance hit.

Try:

```
DECLARE @orderdateFirstDT DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME,@orderdateFirst)
DECLARE @orderdateLastDT DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME,@orderdateLast)

SELECT TOP 100 [RecordID]
       ..........
FROM [Messages].[dbo].[MessagesLog]
WHERE [Arrival] BETWEEN @orderdateFirstDT and @orderdateLastDT
ORDER BY [Arrival] DESC
```

---

Better still would be to change your Stored Procedure parameters to `DATETIME` types so that this conversion isn't even required. But this may require changes outside the scope of this query (for example if you are explicitly setting `varchar` type parameters when calling this sproc).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMessagesByDates]
      (@orderdateFirst DATETIME, 
       @orderdateLast DATETIME)      
AS
BEGIN
```

Comment: Even better: use **appropriate** data types (`DATE` or `DATETIME`) and skip the conversions alltogether!